# Unable to register signal handler in multithread programming in Lua

Tags: multithreading, lua, posix, torch

I am currently using torch to train multi-thread deep learning net, and I need to register a signal handler so that when I press `ctrl+c` I can save weights of the net. But here is the problem, I found that the multi-thread program just ignore the signal and I have totally no idea why...

see code below

```
-- threadTester.lua
local classic = require 'classic'
local threads = require 'threads'
threads.Threads.serialization('threads.sharedserialize')
local tds = require 'tds'
local threadTester = classic.class('threadTester')

function threadTester:_init(atomic)
    self.game = threads.Threads(1,
    function ()
        inner = atomic
    end)
    classic.strict(self)
end

function threadTester:play()
    self.game:addjob(function ()
        while true do
            if inner:get() < 0 then break end
        end
    end)
    -- do some stuff outside
end

return threadTester
```

and

```
local threads = require 'threads'
threads.Threads.serialization('threads.sharedserialize')
local tds = require 'tds'
local signal = require 'posix.signal'

local ctrlpool = threads.Threads(1, function ()
    local tds = require 'tds'
end)

local atomic = tds.AtomicCounter()
atomic:set(1)
nThreads = 4
local ctrlPool = threads.Threads(1)
ctrlPool:addjob(function ()
    local signal = require 'posix.signal'
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, function(signum)
        print('\nSIGINT received')
        print('Ex(c)iting')
        atomic:set(-1)
    end)
end)

ctrlPool:synchronize()

local gamePool = threads.Threads(nThreads, function ()
    threadTester = require 'threadTester'
    player = threadTester(atomic)
end)

for i = 1, nThreads do
    gamePool:addjob(function ()
        print(string.format("begin in thread %d", __threadid))
        local status, err = xpcall(player.play, debug.traceback, player)
        if not status then
            print(string.format('%s', err))
            os.exit(128)
        end
    end)
end

gamePool:synchronize()
gamePool:terminate()
```

In macOS 10.12, torch 7, call `th test.lua`, then press `ctrl+c`, nothing happen.
But if I change `test.lua` as follows

```
local threads = require 'threads'
threads.Threads.serialization('threads.sharedserialize')
local tds = require 'tds'
local signal = require 'posix.signal'

-- local ctrlpool = threads.Threads(1, function ()
--  local tds = require 'tds'
-- end)

local atomic = tds.AtomicCounter()
atomic:set(1)
nThreads = 4
-- local ctrlPool = threads.Threads(1)
-- ctrlPool:addjob(function ()
    local signal = require 'posix.signal'
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, function(signum)
        print('\nSIGINT received')
        print('Ex(c)iting')
        atomic:set(-1)
    end)
-- end)

-- ctrlPool:synchronize()

local gamePool = threads.Threads(nThreads, function ()
    threadTester = require 'threadTester'
    player = threadTester(atomic)
end)

for i = 1, nThreads do
    gamePool:addjob(function ()
        print(string.format("begin in thread %d", __threadid))
        local status, err = xpcall(player.play, debug.traceback, player)
        if not status then
            print(string.format('%s', err))
            os.exit(128)
        end
    end)
end

gamePool:synchronize()
gamePool:terminate()
```

all are as expected

```
> th test.lua
begin in thread 1
begin in thread 2
begin in thread 3
begin in thread 4
^C
SIGINT received
Ex(c)iting
```

but if I use `qlua`

```
>qlua test.lua
begin in thread 1
begin in thread 2
begin in thread 3
begin in thread 4
^C^C^C^C^C^C^Z
[3]  + 15370 suspended  qlua test.lua
```

It fail again...
I am confused... I have no idea why it does not work in `qlua`, and I do see somebody register the signal handler in a ctrl pool...

And if I change the `threadTester.lua` like this

```
local classic = require 'classic'
local threads = require 'threads'
threads.Threads.serialization('threads.sharedserialize')
local tds = require 'tds'
local threadTester = classic.class('threadTester')

function threadTester:_init(atomic)
    self.game = threads.Threads(1,
    function ()
        inner = atomic
    end)
    self.atomic = atomic
    classic.strict(self)
end

function threadTester:play()
    self.game:addjob(function ()
        os.execute("sleep ".. 10)
    end)
    -- do some stuff outside
    while true do
        if self.atomic:get() < 0 then break end
    end
end

return threadTester
```

It functions even more weird (using no-ctrl-pool `test.lua`)

```
th test.lua
begin in thread 1
begin in thread 2
begin in thread 3
begin in thread 4
^C^C^C^C^C
SIGINT received
Ex(c)iting
```

It seems that the signal is received only after `os.execute(something)` finishes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm putting this here in case someone else runs into this issue.
The behaviour being experienced is exactly what the luaposix docs mention:
https://luaposix.github.io/luaposix/modules/posix.signal.html

> Note that posix.signal.signal is implemented with sigaction(2) for consistent semantics across platforms. Also note that installed signal handlers are not called immediatly upon occurrence of a signal. Instead, in order to keep the interperter state clean, they are executed in the context of a debug hook which is called as soon as the interpreter enters a new function, returns from the currently executing function, or after the execution of the current instruction has ended.

So yes, your signal handler only runs after `os.execute` returns.